# Qt: Connect Signals and Slots Across Differnet Files

Tags: c++, signals-slots, qt5

I am a newbie in Qt and C++ programming. I have some problem in my program that i need a solution for.

I have two files MainWindow.h and ChatWindow.h, which contains two classes of MainWindow and ChatWindow.

This is chatwindow.h

```
    namespace Ui {
class ChatWindow;
}

class ChatWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ChatWindow(QWidget *parent=0);
    ~ChatWindow();

private slots:
    void send_chat_fn(pjsua_call_id call_id);
    void rcv_chat_fn(pjsua_call_id call_id);
    void rcv_msg_fn(QString msg);

    void on_pushButton_clicked();
    void on_actionQuit_triggered();

private:
    Ui::ChatWindow *ui;
};
```

And this is mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void add_item(QString buddy_uri);

signals:
    void send_chat(pjsua_call_id call_id);
    void rcv_chat(pjsua_call_id call_id);
    void rcv_msg(QString msg);

private slots:
    void on_actionAdd_Buddy_triggered();
    void on_actionQuit_triggered();
    void on_actionStatus_triggered();
    void on_actionNew_Chat_triggered();
    void on_action_Configuration_triggered();


    void on_listWidget_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

Now i want to connect signals from mainwindow.h to slots in chatwindow.h.

I have tried connection in the constructor of class ChatWindow, but it does not work (i think that is because connections work on instances not on classes). Instance of MainWindow class which i want to connect is in mainwindow.cpp. Defining instances of class ChatWindow in MainWindow gives error:

> Cannot set parent, parent is in different thread

And if i create a new instance in Constructor of ChatWindow, then it doesnt connect to the desired instance.

Its a complete mess. Please help me through this.

Comment: You already answered yourself -- connections work between instances of classes only. So if you have `MainWindow *mw = new MainWindow(); Ui::ChatWindow *cw = new Ui::ChatWindow(); connect(mw, SIGNAL(send_chat(pjsua_call_id)), cw, SLOT(rcv_chat_fn(pjsua_call_id)));`, you have connected these specific two windows (but not all `MainWindow`s and `ChatWindow`s)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But If only it would have been that simple... :)

But problem starts there, the two instances which are to be connected, are in different files.

I will be obliged if you can answer further.